# Random SELECT from PostgreSQL database via Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL and what I need to do is to perform a random `SELECT` query from a certain table in my database (via Hibernate). 
What would be the best way of achieving this?

Here is my code so far:

```
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("RANDOM()"))
```

where `RANDOM()` is the PostgreSQL function. However, there is no property with such a name in the `Entity` class, and therefore, a `HibernateException` gets thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement your own `Order` class, using instructions from [this blog](http://blog.tremend.ro/2008/06/10/how-to-order-by-a-custom-sql-formulaexpression-when-using-hibernate-criteria-api/). You would then use it like `criteria.addOrder(OrderBySqlFormula.sqlFormula("RANDOM() asc"));`